# PHP/SQL UPDATE users row issues

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm a complete noob so I apologise in advance for my ignorance/sheer stupidity.

I'm trying to get a form to submit into the users row on the database. I had this working with INSERT however that just puts it into a new line, rather than the users' (I think) The code below doesn't give many any specific Error, just that there is one (or more likely many) Is this the appropriate way to go about this? And if so could anyone please point out the issues, or point in the direction of a solution.

Thanks!

```
<?php

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASS","DB NAME");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

// escape variables for security
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title']);
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$jobtitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['jobtitle']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
$postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['postcode']);
$telephone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['telephone']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);


$sql = 
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET title='$title', firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', jobtitle='$jobtitle', address='$address', postcode='$postcode', telephone='$telephone', email='$email' WHERE username='$user'");

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Thank you, your details have now been submitted. From here you can Book and Pay for the Events you want to attend.";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Don't mix mysql_* and mysqli_* functions

Comment: Might I suggest that since you're using mysqli to begin with you consider using prepared statements, rather than escaping each variable you can simply pass them in as named parameters to the prepared statement. Will prevent you from ever forgetting to escape a variable if you use it everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing mysql and mysqli functions. Yo9u can't do that:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET title='$title', firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', jobtitle='$jobtitle', address='$address', postcode='$postcode', telephone='$telephone', email='$email' WHERE username='$user'");
```

should be

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET title='$title', firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', jobtitle='$jobtitle', address='$address', postcode='$postcode', telephone='$telephone', email='$email' WHERE username='$user'");
           ^^^      ^^^^^
            THESE MATTER
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace query string as following,

```
$sql = 
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET title='".$title."', firstname='".$firstname."', lastname='".$lastname."', jobtitle='".$jobtitle."', address='".$address."', postcode='".$postcode."', telephone='".$telephone."', email='".$email."' WHERE username='".$user."'");
```

its good practice to put string in double quotes ('".$variable."') in query string.